# Can any one explain this mod rewrite to me?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Here are the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^two$ show.php?id=1
```

So what is the output when you go to :   `two?id=2`

`$_GET['id']` equals 1 or 2?

I run the script, the answer is 1. But I don't understand why? Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: the rule redirects to `show.php?id=1` note there is no variable there, it's a hard link to ID 1

Comment: but the string actually not matching the rules. it not finish by 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ignores URL parameters for RewriteRule:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

> The Pattern will initially be matched against the part of the URL
>   after the hostname and port, and before the query string.
>
> If you wish to match against the hostname, port, or query string, use
>   a RewriteCond with the %{HTTP_HOST}, %{SERVER_PORT}, or
>   %{QUERY_STRING} variables respectively.

Therefore `two?id=2` is matched by your rule as the URL is `^two$` and so is set to `show.php?id=1` and note that the existing query string is replaced when a new one is given as per above link:

> **Modifying the Query String** By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution
>   string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark
>   inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text
>   should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an
>   existing query string, end the substitution string with just a
>   question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA]
>   flag.